# Rails instance variable for record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables, class-variables

Is there any built-in way to attach an instance variable to a *record*?  For example, suppose I have a `User` class with a `foo` `attr_accessor`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  attr_accessor :foo
end
```

If I do

```
u = User.first
u.foo = "bar"
u.foo # -> "bar"
User.find(1).foo # => nil
```

This is the correct behavior and I understand why: the instance variable exists for the *instance* (in memory) and not for the record.  What I want is something like a *record* variable, so that in the above example `u.foo` and `User.find(1).foo` return the same value *within the same instance of my application*.  I don't want persistence: it's not appropriate for `foo` to be a column in the table, it's just appropriate for `foo` to return the same value for the same record during the life cycle of e.g., a controller action, console session, etc.  Nor do I want a class variable via `cattr_accessor`, because there's no reason that `User.find(1).foo` should be the same as `User.find(2).foo`.

The best bet I can come up with is to fake it with a class variable array and instance methods to get/set the appropriate element of the array:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  cattr_accessor :all_the_foos
  self.all_the_foos = Array.new

  def foo
    self.all_the_foos[id]
  end

  def foo= new_foo
    self.all_the_foos[id] = new_foo
  end

end
```

This ALMOST works, but it doesn't work with un-saved records, e.g. `User.new.foo = "bar"` fails.

Comment: I guess it's hard to answer this without knowing what kind of value you want to store. You say you "don't want persistence" but it sounds like you want the instance to keep the same value from one request/session/week to the next, which is the very definition of "persistence." Can you give us some more clues what you're after here?

Comment: The value will be an instance of another class. I want persistence for a length of time somewhere between that of a regular instance variable and a class variable. So, for example, if I triggered a sequence of actions from a controller action, the value would be consistent, but it need not retain its value after the action is complete. It's not a controller variable, that's just an example. I'd rather not go into the specifics of the context b/c it's relatively complex. I'm pretty convinced that the question I've asked is exactly what I need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Thread.current` to set variables that are active within the context of a controller action invocation. Your current implementation doesn't guarantee context reset across calls.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create    :set_thread_var

  def foo
    new_record? ? @foo : Thread.current["User-foo-#{id}"]
  end

  def foo=(val)
    new_record? ? (@foo = val) : (Thread.current["User-foo-#{id}"] = val)
  end

private

  def set_thread_var
    Thread.current["User-foo-#{id}"] = @foo if defined?(@foo)
  end

end
```

Comment: +1 and Thanks.  I had to drop the `attr_accessor`, though, because otherwise my `foo` and `foo=` methods were ignored.  I need to read up on `Thread.current` to really understand what the lifetime is, but this exactly solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a better idea than your class variable solution. To solve your "`new`" problem I'd use `after_initialize`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :init_foos

  cattr_accessor :all_the_foos

  def foo
    self.all_the_foos[id]
  end

  def foo= new_foo
    self.all_the_foos[id] = new_foo
  end

  private
  def init_foos
    @@all_the_foos ||= []
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 and Thanks.  I went with @KandadaBoggu's solution because it's explicitly thread-safe and it doesn't create an array of length N when you access User.last.foo (which was my fault).